# Dynamically adding/removing EC2 instances of an AutoscalingGroup to AWS Dashboard Metric Widget

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am trying to create a dashboard and want a widget to display the CPUUtilization graphs of *ALL* EC2 instances within my autoscaling.
Whenever a new instance gets added by autoscaling rules then  the dashboard widget should include the graph of new EC2 instance automatically and when an instance gets deleted it should remove the graph of that instance.

When I select the autoscaling group as the metric it simply displays one line in the graph although there are 4 instances within that autoscaling groups.

Is that possible?
If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS team release an Lambda function to auto update your dashboard : [here is the link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/keeping-cloudwatch-dashboards-up-to-date-using-aws-lambda/)

The script:

- Loads the specified CloudWatch Dashboard(s)
- Looks for all graph widgets displaying EC2 instance metrics
- Calls EC2 DescribeInstances API with configured parameters to discover the current EC2 instances for that graph in that region
- Updates the widget if needed
- Saves the CloudWatch Dashboards if any widget definition has changed

But it have also limitation :

- it will only update graphs whose first metric is an EC2 instance metric, all other metrics on the graph will be replaced with these metrics
- metrics can not have custom periods or statistics, the graph defaults will be used

Answer (score 5):

A copy paste from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55581103/1766828)

Better late than never, it seems that [CloudWatch has implemented](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudwatch-launches-search-expressions/) a `SEARCH` function with metric expressions.

There are good [examples](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudwatch-launches-search-expressions/) in the documentation:

`SEARCH(' {AWS/EC2,InstanceId} MetricName="CPUUtilization" ', 'Average', 300)`

Comment: I couldn't find a way to display just instances from the AutoScaling group. The filter (WHERE) didn't seem to let me filter by anything other than InstanceID.

Answer (score -2):

Auto scaling groups in AWS are based on Launch configurations, which contain a `monitoring` tickbox. 
If you enable this box, each instance added to the ASG would be launched with Cloudwatch monitoring.
Once you make sure this box is ticked, you can find a way to load the alerts on the new instances joining the group individually to the dashboard.

Comment: I did that but doesnt work.. when I select the AutoScalingGroup it just shows me one line in the graph which is the average of all the EC2 instances. However what I want is that it should show me individual instances communication without me having to add the new instances manually

Comment: You need to find the individual alarms created for each instance and use them instead.

Comment: Yaron can you please elaborate a bit more