# How can I dynamically update my AWS CloudWatch dashboards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have several dashboards in CloudWatch that represent a static view of my infrastructure, for instance, how many instances from an autoscaling worker group are currently running, or the CPU/disk status of various key EC2 instances. However, when I add new instances, I am always stuck manually updating the dashboards to include them in the display.

I'm curious if there is there any way to programmatically populate these dashboards, say through a CLI/API call using an AWS Lambda function? It would be ideal if dashboards could update based on triggers similarly to how Lambda functions know when to execute based on a variety of events/a schedule.

Comment: Similar questions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743459/dynamically-adding-removing-ec2-instances-of-an-autoscalinggroup-to-aws-dashboar

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747550/is-there-a-way-to-create-aws-dashboard-using-cloudformation-or-aws-cli

Comment: Thanks for the additional questions - no answers of use there, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better late than never, it seems that [CloudWatch has implemented](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudwatch-launches-search-expressions/) a `SEARCH` function with metric expressions.

There are good [examples](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudwatch-launches-search-expressions/) in the documentation:

`SEARCH(' {AWS/EC2,InstanceId} MetricName="CPUUtilization" ', 'Average', 300)`

Answer (score 0):

You can update your dashboards through the cloudWatch Dashboards API and through CloudFormation templates

This was released in July 2017 (see [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-api-cloudformation-support-for-amazon-cloudwatch-dashboards/)) and corresponding [PutDashboard API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutDashboard.html) and [CloudFormation documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-dashboard.html).

An example on how to update the dashboards dynamically is explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/keeping-cloudwatch-dashboards-up-to-date-using-aws-lambda/)